# how to start background job when a notification received

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-task, firebase-job-dispatcher

hello everyBody it's my first question here so i hope to get an answer . 
i have an android app and with the help of FCM i am able to receive notifications in the foreground , background and when the app is killed .

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

final String jobTag="copyDb";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

    String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                    .setContentText(notification_message);


    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_action);
    resultIntent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);


    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);




    int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

I want to start a background job when the notification arrive , i used the firebase jobDispatcher :

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("fromUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("fromUser",from_user_id);
    editor.commit();

    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(getApplicationContext()));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(jobDispatcher.class) // the JobService that will be called
            .setTag(jobTag)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

But it's not working while the app is in the background or killed , yet i receive notification .

i tried to move the background task to the FCM onMessageReceived and also got the same problem .

is there any way to trigger a background task when a notification received ??

unusual appreciation for a good answer :))

Comment: To be clear you want when notification arrives to start `AsyncTask` and preform some data downloading or processing?

Comment: exactly , by the way the notifications arrives while app in background or killed.  @Yupi

Comment: Then I think you need to uses services and inside launch AsyncTask

Comment: indeed , but how to make a service to listen to FCM notifications ? @Yupi

Comment: When messages is received start services and in `postExecute` of `AsyncTask` stop services. I think that might work

Comment: i don't think you get me , when i am in the foreground the FCM called successfully and inside it i call background service that download data from the server. 
if the app is in the BACKGROUND google do her job and deliver me the notification **BUT** it's not calling the FCM (code) .
so the problem is how to know when the message is received (**in the Background**) @Yupi

Comment: `AsyncTask` is not equal to `Services`. For example `Services` can be called or run even if app is killed by OS. Take a look: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: i appreciate your replies man , is there any way to start the service when i receive a notification , even if i didn't pressed it ? @Yupi

Comment: @sleemannabwani, did you find any update on this? I am also in need of these functionality to trigger a specific task when client received signal from server[like FCM]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure will this work but you can try. Create a class and extend `Service` and inside create create `AsyncTask` for example something like this:

```
public class TestServices extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    asyncTask.execute();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // preform your task here, downloading saving etc.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Intent intent = new Intent(TestServices.this, TestServices.class);
        stopService(intent);
       }
    }
 }
```

Don't forget to register your `Service` class inside manifest.

Then inside method `onMessageReceived` make some changes. Try this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, TestServices.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0,    notificationIntent, 0);
```

Hope the might help you.